# Having trouble adding custom class to list (C#)

Tags: c#, list, class

I hope my terminology is correct here, still learning all the right lingo.

I've created a custom class using the following code:

```
    public class inputData
{
    public string type;
    public int time;
    public int score;
    public int height;
}
```

And I'd like to create a list that contains that class, as I've done here:

```
List<inputData> inputList = new List<inputData>();
```

I'm now trying to Add to that list and I'm having trouble. I've tried both of the following and still no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
inputList.Add(new inputData("1", 2, 3, 4));

inputList.type.Add("1");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [**object initializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

**Change**

```
inputList.Add(new inputData("1", 2, 3, 4));
```

**To**

```
inputList.Add(new inputData{type="1", time=2, score=3, height=4});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly - I thought I was close, just couldn't get the syntax quite right.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had to 'wait 10 minutes' according to the pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

Problem isn't with the list, but with the inputData class - you're trying to use undefined contructor. Add the contructor into the inputData class:

```
public inputData(string type, int time, int score, int height)
{
  this.type=type; this.time=time, this.score=score, this.height=height
}
```

Second, follow C# conventions - name of class should start with uppercase, public field replace with C# properties. But it's not the problem your code doesn't work.